# How to pass any object into a generic overview with colum specifications in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, generic-programming

I am trying to create an overview that can take in any model and fill a grid with the data from that model in Angular.

Let's say I have the following model:

```
export class Incident {
   id: number;
   number: number;
   reportDate: string;
   startDate: string;
   endDate: string;
   vehicleNumber: number;
   licensePlate: string;
   location: string;
   supplier: string;
   pickupLocation: string;
   causeOfFailure: string;
   cause: string;
   descriptionExternal: string;
   status: string;
}
```

I have a service that returns this data as Json and it is being mapped to an array of Incident objects.

The overview is built based on the settings I pass into the component which looks like this:

```
export class OverviewSettings {
   title: string;
   collapsible: boolean;
   pagination: boolean;
   pageSize: number;
   primaryColumnSpecifications: ColumnSpecifications[];
   rowItems: any[];
}
```

And the ColumnSpecifications:

```
export class ColumnSpecifications {
   name: string;
   dataType: number;
   columnSize: string;
}
```

The items I am going to loop through in the overview are of type any[] because I need it to be able to process every model i pass into it. For now I am passing an array of Incidents.

The thing I am trying to achieve is to be able to pass on which column is going to show which property from my model.

My question is: How do I make this overview usable for all models?

Answer (score 1):

Can you give an example for what you want to do ?

Example for generic class:

```
class KeyValuePair<T,U>
{ 
    private key: T;
    private val: U;

    setKeyValue(key: T, val: U): void { 
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

```
class Department<T> {

   //different types of employees
   private employees:Array<T> = new Array<T>();

   public add(employee: T): void {
      this.employees.push(employee);
   }

}
```

Comment: I want to be able to specify the property of the model and link it to a column in the settings so i can define what the overview will look like and what properties are being shown.

Comment: Look into example i have given.

Comment: I don't need a generic class like this, i need to specify what column is linked to which property of any given model defined in my settings model